# find all natural numbers for which polynomial is complete square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can one find all natural numbers  $n$ for which $n^2 + n + 29$ is  square of some natural number? Can someone give at lease hint? (I am looking for method which does not include  Legendre symbol).

Comment: what's a complete square?

Comment: I edited, put "square of some natural number"

Comment: $ n^2$ is a Square and $(n+1)^2$ is the next square. Beteuern These Numbers is No square. If n is large enough $n^2+n+29$ is beteween these two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $n^2+n+29=(n+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{115}{4}$

Comment: if we assume here that $(n+ 1/2)^2 + 115/4 = m^2$, then we have $(2n+1)^2= 4 m^2 -115$. Could you please proceed?

Comment: @User154 Then $(2m)^2-(2n+1)^2 = 115$.

Answer (score -1):

Given that cit. "square of some natural number", we know its form being
$(n+a)^2 = (n+a)*(n+a) = n^2+2an+a^2$

Compare this to your $n^2+n+29$ to find

$n+29 =2an+a^2=(2n+a)a$

From here, you should be able to solve for $n=4$ and $a=3$, so $(4+3)(4+3)=49$ is your square.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a practice from programming, but this is a math forum. Use juxtaposition $x y$, `x \times y` to get $x \times y$ or `x \cdot y` to get $x \cdot y$.

Comment: Are you aware that $n=4$ is no the only solution?